# Extract all patterns using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm implementing the pattern extraction from a particular string.
The pattern should start with Column( (which means particular column in Excel data input) or Cell( (which means particular cell in Excel data input).

- Input String = "Column(F)/100 + Cell(B,2)/10"
- Expected output: Column(F), Cell(B,2).

Source code:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
Regex patternParser = new Regex(@"(?:Column\()\S+\).+?|(?:Cell\()\S+\).+?", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match m in patternParser.Matches(VarEval))
{
     result.Add(m.Value);
}
```

I got the result: Column(F)/ and Cell(B,2)/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\b(?:Column|Cell)\b\(.*?\)
```

You can simply do this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/26

Comment: I don't understand the usage of \b here, can you elaborate more on it? Tks.

Comment: @Thinhbk `\b` is word boundary.It will disallow partail matches like `someColumn` or `randomeCell`.It will strictly match only those 2 words

Comment: tks for your explanation. It would be very nice if you can give answer to this stupid question: why the pattern used in the question does not work?

Comment: @Thinhbk it works.See https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/30 ... just that `.+?` that is not needed.remove that and it works fine

Comment: Tks a lot. aha, I used that token because I just want to get the first existence of the character to prevent the greedy characteristic of Regex. So somewhat I have wrong understanding about Regex. :(

Comment: @Thinhbk if you want first instance and prevent greedy then use `(?:Column\()\S+?\)|(?:Cell\()\S+?\)`

Comment: @Thinhbk: Yes, your regex works for your input without `.+?`, but I'd also like to add that the second `\b` in this suggested regex is not necessary because the next character we want to match is `(`, a non-word character. Also, this regex will fail in case you have `Column(F(A - V))` (it will only catch `Column(F(A - V)` without the last `)`).

Answer (score 1):

here it is: `(?i)(?:Column|Cell)\([^()]+?\)`

```
List<string> result = Regex.Matches("Column(F)/100 + Cell(B,2)/10",
                                    @"(?i)(?:Column|Cell)\([^()]+?\)")
                           .Cast<Match>()
                           .Select(m=>m.Value)
                           .ToList();
```